# How to create a SELECT statement involving a subtype

Tags: mysql, select, erd, subtypes

Okay, so all I'm trying to do here is "list" the managers who supervised the employee that charged a customer $100 for a rental on November 1st, 1998.

My issue is that I don't know how to select the managers' name because they're listed under MANAGER, which is a subtype of the EMPLOYEE supertype. I've posted my EER diagram below:

[image]

Comment: The diagram is helpful, but is difficult to read.  What can you do to provide clarity.  Reducing your diagram focus on the main question would be helpful.  FWIW Based on the diagram, I suspect that the Manager_ID is likely the same as the Employeer_ID of the manager as indicated by the relationship with the (D).  Just guessing of course.

Answer (score 0):

How you do the select depends on your table design.  Your EER depicts the entities, relationships and attributes nicely, but doesn't say anything about table design.  (That's as it should be, IMO).  A relational schematic would give those details.

If you are interested in how to design tables for a subtype (or subclass) situation here are two alternative techniques for you to explore:

http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html

And there is a technique often used when tables have a one to one relationship to each other.  You can see it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key